# Electron configuration of atom under LS coupling

Tags: term-symbols

We express the state of atom like $(\mathrm{1s})^2(\mathrm{2s})^2(\mathrm{2p})^6(\mathrm{3s})^2(\mathrm{3p})^6(\mathrm{4s})^1$,   $^2\mathrm{S}_{1/2}$, for example. This notation supposes the coupling of angular momentum is LS coupling.
Under the LS coupling, however, $J = L + S = \sum l_i  + \sum s_i$ and $J_z$ is the good quantum number. We cannot determine each electrons orbital angular momentum, but the notation written above specifies it. How is it justified?